# Bootstrap Tabs: Show Element Across All Tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it would be quite awesome if it is.

Basically, I am using bootstrap tabs and I have about 5 separate tabs.

Each tab offers different functionality, however, I'd like to be able to show one div across ALL tabs. For example, you view tab 1, then click on tab 2, that div shows in tab 1 AND tab 2.

Here is the catch... I'm using ASP.net, so I can't use jQuery to move the elements between tabs on change as it would mess with .Net...

The only way I was thinking was somehow possibly setting a super high z-index on the div I want to show across all tabs, however, I believe that that won't work if the tab it originates in is hidden.

Here is some code as an example:

```
 <div class="tabbable">
       <ul id="applicant-tabs" class="nav nav-tabs tab-padding tab-space-3 tab-blue applicant-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#registration-tab" class="registration-tab" data-color="#c0504d" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
           <li><a href="#validation-tab" class="validation-tab" data-color="#9bbb59" data-toggle="tab">Validation</a></li>
       </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
          <div class="tab-pane in active form-horizontal" id="registration-tab">
             <div>content that is only shown in registration tab</div>
             <div>content that can be seen in all tabs</div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane in form-horizontal" id="validation-tab">
             <div>content that is only shown in validation tab</div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about moving the content that you want across all tabs outside of the `tab-pane` `<div>` and put it just before the closing `</div>` of `tab-content`.  Then it's just a case of styling the two 'boxes'.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-content" style="overflow-x:hidden;">
  <div class="tab-pane in active form-horizontal" id="registration-tab">
    <div>content that is only shown in registration tab</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane in form-horizontal" id="validation-tab">
    <div>content that is only shown in validation tab</div>
  </div>
  <div>content that can be seen in all tabs</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tab-pane > div,
.all-tabs-content {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ececec;
}

.tab-pane > div {
  float: left;
}

.all-tabs-content {
  float: right;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

**http://jsbin.com/OxoZoRIp/2/edit**

Comment: Hi David - thanks - the only thing is, with the tabs, this div would appear in the "right" column, not below the tabs - know what i mean? basically, the first (left) div in each tab is only wide enough to give room so that the right div can show up adjacent - does that make sense?

Comment: I'm a bit lost, can you mock it up in an image?

Comment: That's just CSS.  I've updated the answer, hopefully it helps.